# Why did Yaakov ask Yosef to swear in the way he did?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, tznius-modesty, brit-milah, vayechi, nedarim-shevuot

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22109/why-did-avraham-ask-eliezer-to-swear-in-the-way-he-did)

In Bereshis 47:29 Yaakov asks Yosef to "put his hand under his thigh" (a euphemism) and swear not to bury him in Egypt. Here, unlike by Avraham, there is no indication that the mitzvah of milah is more important to Yaakov than any other (such as learning torah or gid hanasheh). Why then did he ask Yosef to swear in that way?

Comment: Why not gid hanashe? ;)

Comment: @HodofHod i added that to my question, i've never seen a commentary who says that but it would make sense

Comment: @HodofHod nikmasi: R Waxman suggested it in one of his posts http://parsha.blogspot.com/2012/01/what-nekitas-chefetz-was-there-if.html

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm ready to start a petition to include him in the next version of mikros gedolos

Comment: @nikmasi Start it, and I'll sign. http://www.change.org/petition

Comment: @DoubleAA careful what you wish for https://www.change.org/petitions/whoever-publishes-mikros-gedolos-include-rabbi-joshua-waxman-s-chiddushim also, someone should tell him.

Comment: @nikmasi Better post this in chat then. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7630238#7630238

Comment: "put his hand under his thigh" (a euphemism) - a euphemism for what? Which rabbi says that this is a euphemism?

Answer (score 6):

From [KolTorah.org](http://www.koltorah.org/volume_18/VaYechi-Shemot.html)

The [Maharal](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42842&st=&pgnum=393) commenting on Rashi, answers that

> this was the way the people back then made Shevu’ot; the one swearing would place their hands under the other thigh of the person he is swearing to (as the [Ibn Ezra points out in his commentary to Breishit 24:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=293) and confirmed by Da’at Mikra ad. loc.). Yaakov thought that if he did not do the Shevuah this way, when Yosef would ask him to go and bury his father, Paroh would respond that he did not make the Shevuah according to the law of the land, and, therefore, the Shevuah was null and void.

The Maharal continues to say that the reason Rashi gave the [explanation by Avraham](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219/showrashi/true#v2) that the bris was his nekitas cheifetz is because it wouldn't make sense to say that Avraham was following the world's custom. Avraham had no reason to have Eliezer swear like the custom, unlike Yaakov, who was concerned that Pharaoh wouldn't recognize anything else.

---

The ibn Ezra himself would probably give the same explanation for both Avraham and Yaakov.

Much thanks to @b a for helping me understand the Maharal correctly.

Comment: It would seem the question is premised not on this explanation but that he took the oath this way because of nekitat chefetz

Comment: Isn't this also the same method that Avraham made Eliezer swear to him?

Comment: @BruceJames See the link at the top of the question

Comment: @DoubleAA The very first words of the Maharal are almost exactly what nikmasi asked. Namely, since swearing under Yaakov's thigh isn't a nekitas cheifetz, why do it? _"קשיא לי למה השביע במילה ולא
 בנקיטת חפץ"_?

Comment: @HodofHod What I mean is this answer is perfectly valid for Avraham's case also. If you view Avraham's case as some halachik construct and not an ancient middle eastern honor code, then you probably wouldn't want to say only Yaakov's case is that.

Comment: @DoubleAA See edit.

Comment: What you recently added in with the edit doesn't seem in my opinion to be the intention of the Maharal. I think he's saying that this is why *Rashi* didn't comment the same way as he did earlier.

Comment: @ba What Rashi? I don't see where the Maharal mentions Rashi at all.

Comment: @HodofHod He doesn't mention Rashi by name, but he's commenting on him (the dibur hamatchil of the piece is a quote from Rashi). [This edition](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42842&st=&pgnum=393) makes it a little more clear.

Comment: @ba How about now?

Comment: It fits with what the Maharal seems to me to be saying.

Answer (score 0):

The pirush Maharzo on the Medrash Rabba perek 59 siman 8 d.h. bitzaar says Yaakov learned to swear like this from Avraham. The Eitz Yosef there in the name of Yaphe Toar says similarly even though Yaakov was young by his circumcision he still made Yosef swear in this manner, one can say that after Avraham swore like this, the tzadik took his way.