# Why did Yaakov Avinu tell Yosef to place his hand by his thigh?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, brit-milah, nedarim-shevuot, vayechi

In parshas Vayechi 47 29 Yaakov Avinu tells Yosef to place his hand by his thigh. We find this expression used by Avraham Avinu in Chayei Sarah 24 2 with an explenation by Rashi that an object used for a mitzvah needed to be held for the shvua and Avraham chose his mitzvas mila because it was his first mitzva, and he got it through pain, and it was precious to him. 
None of this applies to Yaakov, so why did he choose it? There is even a Medrash that says Yaakov was born without a foreskin so there is no object of mitzva at all.

Comment: @Scimonster I'll second that:/

Comment: You can also cast a close vote, you know.

Comment: @Scimonster i just did. Wow. That was actually fun in a shoot yourself in the leg with a paintball kind of way.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3373/5323

Comment: @user6591 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/266359

Answer (score 0):

You say that none of the reasons listed for Avraham apply to Yaacov; I would have to disagree with the primary reason given by Rashi; swearing while holding a sacred object. Even if Yaacov was born circumcised, this would still require drawing of blood ([Shabbat 135a](http://www.come-and-hear.com/shabbath/shabbath_135.html#135a_2)), and hence still be a davar shel kedusha (object of holiness/mitzvah object).

And thus, would also have caused him pain, and hence would be precious etc.

So you see, all three would still apply.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3373/5323

Comment: @user6591 its case of doubt doesnt push off Shabbos

Comment: @user6591 then the 1st and 3rd reasons

Comment: @user6591 R. Simeon b. Eleazar said: Beth Shammai and Beth Hillel did not differ concerning him who is born circumcised that you must cause a few drops of the covenant blood to flow from him, because it is a suppressed foreskin:2

Comment: To clarify: my above comment wasn't a request to delete; I was just letting you know this answer was under discussion for being remarkable ;-) ...you know, if you want to post an answer to [the other question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23495/why-did-yaakov-ask-yosef-to-swear-in-the-way-he-did), you still could.